# iOS 9.1 update.

Tags: iphone, ios, software-update

I really liked the new iOS 9.1 update until I discovered that the music app was changed. I went in and I had just downloaded new songs and I wanted to create a new playlist. I was so excited to listen to them but my bubble was then burst. I couldn't figure out how to make a new playlist! And then I couldn't find all my other songs!? And I share the music app with my brother and he deleted all my old playlist so now I have about 4 songs. How do I add a playlist? And how do stop sharing the app with my brother?

Answer (score 1):

To add a new playlist, go to your music app, on the bottom left corner there should be a "My music" icon, there are a "Edit" and a  "New" button, click on "New" and you will be able to create a new playlist.

For the sharing problem, you should be able to see "All Playlists" displayed, click on it and tick the "Only offline music" toggle, it should solve the issue.